# How to get Invoice collection magento 2?

Tags: magento2, invoice

i want to get all invoice collection? 
Here below is my code but not working

```
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\shippingchargesFactory
     */
    protected $invoice_collection;

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\Status
     */
    protected $_status;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\shippingchargesFactory $shippingchargesFactory
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepository $invoice_collection,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $this->invoice_collection = $invoice_collection;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->invoice_collection->create()->getList();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to collect the Invoice Collection of Logged-in Customers. How did you solve this issue? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can get Invoice collection.

**Using Repository interface**

`Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface::getList`

**Another way is**

```
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepositoryFactory $invoiceRepositoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria        
) {

     $this->invoiceRepositoryFactory = $invoiceRepositoryFactory;
    $this->searchCriteria = $searchCriteria;
}


/**
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups();
    $invoiceRepo = $this->invoiceRepositoryFactory->create();
    $invoiceRepoCollection = $invoiceRepo->getList($this->searchCriteria);
    $items = $invoiceRepoCollection->getItems();
    print_r($invoiceRepoCollection->getSize());
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        print_r($item->getData());
    }
}
```