# Invoice Items Collection

Tags: magento2, invoice

Which **class::method()** is responsible for Invoice Items Collection in the Invoice to Items Selection in the New Invoice page?
I just want to make some custom filter in this collection.
Can anyone guide me please.

Comment: I guess that you want to the function or class which provide list of item which able for invoice

Comment: Yes ! just want to known which function return invoice collection that set at New Invoice Page at Invoice of Items section

Comment: i make custom attribute in sales_order_item table that name is "current_admin_id" and save ids. Now just display those item in invoice list that is belong to current login admin.
I make the filter on those function. But exactly i don't which function return invoice collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Module/Sale/Model/Order/Invoice.php`
 and method is `getAllItems()` is responsible that collection of invoice items in New Invoice page. 
I create `afterGetAllItems()` plugin for making custom collection (custom invoice items)

After that you can modify `Subtotal` and `Grand Total`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepositoryFactory $invoiceRepositoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria        
) {

     $this->invoiceRepositoryFactory = $invoiceRepositoryFactory;
    $this->searchCriteria = $searchCriteria;
}


/**
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups();
    $invoiceRepo = $this->invoiceRepositoryFactory->create();
    $invoiceRepoCollection = $invoiceRepo->getList($this->searchCriteria);
    $items = $invoiceRepoCollection->getItems();
    print_r($invoiceRepoCollection->getSize());
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        print_r($item->getData());
    }
}
```

or

Using Repository interface

```
Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface::getList
```

Another way is

```
Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory
```

check this link [How to get Invoice collection magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261169/how-to-get-invoice-collection-magento-2)

Answer (score 1):

You want to get `class and method`  which is responsible for providing  available items during new invoice creation at New Invoice page then take a look at Below class:

[`Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\NewAction`](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/NewAction.php#L16)

and this class  below code

`$invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $invoiceItems);`

is responsible for available items for new invoice creation

So, if want to modify on this item collection then you have to work  on

[`Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService::prepareInvoice`](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Service/InvoiceService.php#L150)

that function  you can get order item  see `foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {`

Comment: `foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
}`

i want to try nested foreach under this foreach bracket but code is not enter this loop. 
then i try to print_r(orderItem) it broken the web page to much data come

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: `public function prepareInvoice(Order $order, array $qtys = [])
    {
        $invoice = $this->orderConverter->toInvoice($order);
        $totalQty = 0;
        $qtys = $this->prepareItemsQty($order, $qtys);
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
             // print_r($orderItem); die('die');
            foreach ($orderItem as $items){
                print_r($items);
            }
//magento core code her 
}`

code is not enter in my foreach loop

Comment: i save custome attribute ("seller_id") in sales_order_item table and save seller_ids there.
Now i want to apply filter on just display those items in Invoice Item section in New invoice page.
I already apply filter in order view page. just those items display in which seller_id match. Same i want this filter in invoice page